# Как вывести информацию в отдельной форме

Tags: c#, winforms

У меня программа для решения уравнения методом касательной в C#.

В одной форме вводится уравнение, а результат решения уравнения должен выводится во второй форме в `TextBox`.

Как это сделать?

Comment: Боюсь что вопрос сформулирован слишком размыто. Поясните, пожалуйста, какая у вас задача с точки зрения пользователя. Лучше добавить эту информацию в вопрос, а не в комментарии.

Comment: @Uranus You sir, are a gentleman and a scholar!

Answer (score 2):

Самый несложный способ вот такой.

1. В классе формы, в которую  будет выводится результат, объявите дополнительный конструктор с параметром. Через параметр можно будет передавать результат.

   ```
   public class ShowResultForm : Form {
     public ShowResultForm() {
       InitializeComponents();
     }
     public ShowResultForm(string result) : this() {
       resultTextBox.Text = result;
     }
   }
   ```
2. Вот таким образом можно будет показать результат:

   ```
   public void ShowResultButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     string result = GetResult();
     using (ShowResultForm showResultForm = new ShowResultForm(result)) {
       showResultForm.ShowDialog(this);
     }
   }
   ```

*ShowResultForm создается в блоке `using` совсем не целью запутать новичка. Он необходим для того, чтобы после закрытия формы выполнился ее метод Dispose, позволив компонентам формы освободить ресурсы и избежать утечек памяти. Этот метод не вызывается автоматически если форму показать с помощью метода ShowDialog а не Show.*

Comment: Ох, все испортили последним абзацем.

Comment: @Igor, так мне и поправить не сложно. Пока только невдомек где проблема :-) То что написано в последнем абзаце, многажды приходилось объяснять и показывать. Это моя личная боль. Если дело только в некорректной терминологии или плохо раскрытой мысли, это поправимая проблема.

Comment: Мы, вероятно, вкладываем разный смысл в слово "уничтожаются".

Comment: Уничтожается или нет, но портится она от этого уж точно :-). Что поделать, влияние нерусских источников. Порой знаешь как сказать на английском, но на русском с первого раза не получается.

Comment: +1 *(8 символов нужно...)*

Answer (score 1):

**Первая форма, в которой решается уравнение:**

```
var result = 100; //здесь результат вычисления вашего уравнения

Form2 MyForm = new Form2(result);// вызываем пользовательский конструктор второй формы
MyForm.Show();
```

**Вторая форма, в которой выводим результат:**

```
public var result {get;set} //автореализуемое свойство

public Form2(var MyValue) //Пользовательский конструктор
{
  result = MyValue;
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  textBox_REZULT.Text = result; // Выводим в textBox результат
}
```

*На заметку. Конструктор по умолчанию, если будет использоваться и указан пользовательский конструктор, должен быть указан явно.*